Is there a way to stop iphone and android from recording the sounds coming from their own speaker?
I am building a communication app and need to implement echo cancellation i.e. the sound coming from the speaker should not go back into the microphone. I am unable to find clear documentation on whether the phones implement this at the hardware level. In my experiments, the sound from the phone speaker does get recorded by the microphone.
I am using flutter for my app development. I tested it on an iPhone 12.
